# Get DOM element in DalekJS

Tags: javascript, dom, dalekjs

I have a problem with my DalekJS test. I would like get a value from a DOM element, but I don't know how to do so.

This is what I've tried:

```
test.open('http://www.1915-1918.org/memoriale/')
    .waitForElement('.numItemsFil')
    .execute(function ()    {
        this.assert.ok((document.getElementsByClassName('numItemsFil')[0].innerText ===
                               document.getElementsByClassName('item').length));
    })
    .done();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [assert.text(...)](http://dalekjs.com/docs/assertions.html#meth-text) method?

Something like this should work I think:

```
test.open('http://www.1915-1918.org/memoriale/')
    .waitForElement('.numItemsFil:first-child')
    .assert.text('.numItemsFil:first-child', document.getElementsByClassName('item').length, 'Text matches item count')
    .done();
```